# What will be the value of this variable?

Tags: perl, variables

I have to troubleshoot some elderly Perl code, but I can't figure out what the value of `$teilnehmer` will be in this code.

```
# Teilnehmer   einlesen
foreach ( $c = 0; $c <= @htmllines; $c++ ) {

    if ( $htmllines[$c] !~ /(<!--responses: $delkursnr-->0)/ ) {

        if ( $htmllines[$c] =~ /<!--responses: $delkursnr-->(.*)/ ) {
            $rspbegin = $c;
        }

        $teilnehmer = $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the text which is match the regex in the if statement

Comment: That's the second `if` (the inner one). If it fails to match then I guess `$_` will be `undef`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach ($c = 0;$c <= @htmllines;$c++) {
    if ($htmllines[$c] !~ /(<!--responses: $delkursnr-->0)/) {
        if ($htmllines[$c] =~ /<!--responses: $delkursnr-->(.*)/){
            $rspbegin = $c;
        };
        $teilnehmer= $_;
    }
}
```

This means that:

```
$teilnehmer = $htmllines[$c]
```

It's the same as:

```
 foreach ($c = 0;$c <= @htmllines;$c++) {
    if ($htmllines[$c] !~ /(<!--responses: $delkursnr-->0)/) {
        if ($teilnehmer = $htmllines[$c] =~ /<!--responses: $delkursnr-->(.*)/){
            $rspbegin = $c;
        };
    }
}
```

More info about $_ can be found on Google

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done Perl and I don't have it installed here so I can't test it.

It looks like the code is supposed to find the last element in `@htmllines` which satisfies some regex-related conditions, and store the array element into the variable `$teilnehmer` and its index in the array into the variable `$rspbegin`. Note that a particular iteration through the loop might set the value of `$teilnehmer` but not `$rspbegin`. So they don't actually correspond to the same entry in the array.

Also, the loop is bounded by `$c <= @htmllines`. This means that the loop will run one final time after the end of the array, and with `$htmllines[$c] = undef`. I don't know how the outer `if` block would handle this, since it's a negative regex match. If the negative match returns falsey then this isn't a problem - it will ignore that case. But if it returns truthy then `$teilnehmer` will be set to `undef`. And this is the last iteration of the loop, so the value won't be overridden later.

Another thing: What is the value of `$delkursnr`? Does it contain any regex special characters? Regex special characters are the following: `^$()[].?*+{}|\`... I may have missed some. (`/-` should be OK though.) You should replace `$delkursnr` in the regexes with `\Q$delkursnr\E` in the regexes in case it does have special characters. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters .